# does .so size affect virtual function performance

Tags: c++, linux, performance

Recently, I met a performance problem. In Vtune result, virtual function cost is always the no.1 cost, when I reduce the so size which from 48M to 37M, the performance seems better, raise up 3.9%.

I wanna know, does the  .so size realy affect virtual function performance, if so, why? Thanks!

Comment: No, but it affects paging locality and various other things like that.

Comment: As previous commenter mentioned, size can affect paging (and also cache performance). Noteworthy is that Linux libs seem to be much larger than WinBloat libs:https://www.openoffice.org/tools/performance/linux/index.html

Comment: Also, here is a link about symbol hashing and lookup speed optimizations for ELF: https://blogs.oracle.com/ali/entry/the_cost_of_elf_symbol

Comment: @ErikAlapää, it seems helpful for my question, i‘ll try again, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not purely *size* (though of course that affects paging after the program is loaded), but the number of *adjustments* the loader must make when loading a program.  You can see that measured by setting the environment variable

```
LD_DEBUG=statistics
```

Virtual functions in particular will require a lot of adjustments during loading.  For discussion on this,

- [Measure time taken dynamically linking at program startup?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24625386/measure-time-taken-dynamically-linking-at-program-startup)
- [Faster C++ program startups
  by improving runtime linking efficiency.](http://objprelink.sourceforge.net/index.html)
- [Position Independent Executable (PIE) Performance](https://securityblog.redhat.com/tag/gcc-security-feature/)

Answer (score 0):

I use the method from the article(blogs.oracle.com/ali/entry/the_cost_of_elf_symbol) which is provided by @ErikAlapää, use RTLD_LAZY instead of RTLD_NOW when dlopen the so. However, it seems nothing help. While I compile it with less objects, it becomes better. It seems paging cache does affect the process performance.